# How to convert DataTable to object type List in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, generic-list

I want to convert `DataTable` to `List<object>` in C#. Here is my code. But it is not working. Please help me

```
public List<object> ShowMessage()
{
    List<object> obj = new List<object>();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");

    dt.Rows.Add("1","AAA");
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "BBB");
    dt.Rows.Add("3", "CCC");

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        obj.Add(dr);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

**This is the Error--**

[image]

Comment: Which type of your object? how it is no working?

Comment: Which part isn't working? That code doesn't look wrong.

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Have you tried to debug it? From my perspective everything should be fine...

Comment: That is simple: `return dt.AsEnumerable().Cast<object>().ToList()` ;-)

Comment: i want to bind a datagird. i will use this list as a datasource.

Comment: Can you edit your post and specify your exact requirements and exact problems?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have any Typed DataType for list object something like this

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do like this

```
private List<MyObj> test(DataTable dt)
{
       
    var convertedList = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select new MyObj() 
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(rw["ID"]),
            Name = Convert.ToString(rw["Name"])
        }).ToList();

    return convertedList;
}
```

or if you still want `List<object>` then do like this

```
private List<object> GetListByDataTable(DataTable dt)
{

    var reult = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            Name = Convert.ToString(rw["Name"]),
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(rw["ID"])
        }).ToList();

    return reult.ConvertAll<object>(o => (object)o);
}
```

or follow this it has generic resolution too https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/

Answer (score 8):

I hope what you are trying to do is insert the objects in the data table (which probably are returned from a query) in to a List.

```
public List<object> ShowMessage2(DataTable dtInput)
    {
        List<object> objectList = new List<object>();

        foreach(DataRow dr in dtInput.Rows)
        {
            MyObj newObj = new MyObj();
            newObj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);  // Beware of the possible conversion errors due to type mismatches
            newObj.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();

            objectList.Add(newObj);
        }
        return objectList;
    }

public class MyObj
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

---

Just saw your addition to the question!  I can't understand why you try to generate a list if your intention is just to display the data in a gird view, which you can do in a single line!!!

```
List<object> obj = new List<object>();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "AAA");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "BBB");
dt.Rows.Add("3", "CCC");

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; // THIS IS ALL U NEED! Just bind the DataTable to the grid as data source!
```

Answer (score 2):

The DataRow need to be created before adding it to the DataRow collection.

For instance,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "1";
        dr[1] = "AAA";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ... likewise

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            obj.Add(dr);
        }
```

Now the List should hold the Rows. Let me know if it works.