# Get strong types from a DataTable in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, datatable, strong-typing

I have no choice but to work with the following:

- I'm given a non-strongly-typed `DataTable` whose columns are known
- I have accompanying POCO model classes which can be annotated by attributes if needed
- I have to stick with .NET 3.5
- I want to get something that exposes the `DataTable` as a generic collection, list or enumerable, etc. of the strong POCO type (or at least pass it a `typeof`() and get back an object which can be cast).

The table could have a large number of columns. I don't want to have to string-index the data table for each one. I seem to remember a mechanism whereby a framework used reflection to do this, but I can't find it.

I don't care which technology I end up using (be it EF, Linq, etc.) so long as it stays within the Microsoft stack (I can't use third-party APIs). I'd prefer not to create EF design files, nor have VS create the model class for me. How do I do this as painlessly as possible?

Comment: Here is a similar question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834059/how-to-convert-datatable-to-object-type-list-in-c-sharp]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834059/how-to-convert-datatable-to-object-type-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: First of all, that question was closed as 'not a real question'. Second of all, all of the answers involved string-indexing the data table, which I really want to avoid.