# How can I return a object's List from a Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have written a class to execute stored procedures and retrieve data from the database, currently it has 2 methods, one return a SqlDataReader and the other return a DataTable.

I need to write a new method to return a List (like EF), but it must be generic because it will be used in different applications, so it will have to return LIST (IEnumerable) of many classes depend on the situation.

Any example?

I can read english and spanish.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying to want a function that can call a stored procedure and return a list of objects, where each object in the list is created from a row in the procedure results?  If so, it sounds like what you want is an Object-Relational-Mapper (ORM).  Entity Framework is Microsoft's ORM and it's pretty complex.  I would recommend Dapper http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4e3f7/dapper-king-of-micro-orm-C-Sharp-net/, it's a lot more lightweight and easy to get started with.

Comment: Did you see these links?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834059/how-to-convert-datatable-to-object-type-list-in-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list