# Issue with searlization

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My requirement is to create customerwisefolder and generage customerwise xml in that folder. I have taken the entire customer list, taking each record to create xml file within that folder. But here the problem is that I am not able to add each customer row as a list:
Any idea to solve this problem.?

```
     for (int i = 0; i < dsCustomer.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {                     

                    string CustomerName = Convert.ToString(dsCustomer.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
                    string folderName = FilePath + "Files\\Customers\\" + CustomerName;
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customers));
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    Customers lstCustomer = new Customers();                
                    lstCustomer.Add(dsCustomer.Tables[0].Rows[i]);
                    serializer.Serialize(memStream, lstCustomer);
                    FileStream file = new FileStream(folderName + "\\CustomerDetails.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    memStream.WriteTo(file);
                    file.Close();

                }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DataTable to object type List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834059/how-to-convert-datatable-to-object-type-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @CodeCaster  Let me check. Thank you

Comment: @CodeCaster  I checked but sorry, still confusing....

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add something of type `object` to a list that expects something of type `BackupType.Customer`. Try casting your data

```
lstCustomer.Add((BackupType.Customer)dsCustomer.Tables[0].Rows[i]);
```